# What is the best practice when adding data in one-to-many relationship?

Tags: api, entity-framework, .net-6.0, one-to-many

I am developing a website for a beauty salon. There is an admin part of the website, where the esthetician can add a new care. A care is linked to a care category (all cares related to hands, feets, massages, ...). To solve this I wrote this code into the CareRepository in the .NET API :

```
public async Task<Care?> AddAsync(Care care)
    {
        // var dbCareCategory = await this._careCategoryRepository.GetByNameAsync(care.CareCategoryName);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(care.CareCategoryName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(care.CareCategoryName))
            return null;

        var dbCareCategory = await this._instituteDbContext.CareCategories
            .Where(careCategory => Equals(careCategory.Name, care.CareCategoryName))
            .Include(careCategory => careCategory.Cares)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (dbCareCategory == null || dbCareCategory.Cares.Contains(care))
            return null; // TODO : improve handling

        dbCareCategory.Cares.Add(care);

        await this._instituteDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return care;
    }
```

My problem here is that I am a bit struggling with the best practice to have, because in order to add a care to a category, I have to get the category first.  At the first place, I called the CareCategoryRepository to get the care (commented line). But then, EF was not tracking the change, so when I tried to add the care, it was not registered in the database. But once I call the category from the CareRepository, EF tracks the change and saves the Care in the database.

I assume this is because when calling from another repository, it is a different db context that tracks the changes of my entity. Please correct me if my assumption is wrong.

So, I am wondering, what is the best practice in this case ?

1. Keep doing what I am doing here, there is no issue to be calling the category entities from the care repository.
2. Change my solution and put the AddCare method into the CareCategoryRepository, because it makes more sense to call the categories entities from the CareCategoryRepository.
3. Something else ?

This solution works fine, however I feel like it may not be the best way to solve this.

Comment: Care is a db entity (i.e directly mapped to a table), so if you accept Care as a parameter, it already should be in a proper state. Canonical repository implementations accept some higher level business entities, maps them to EF entities correctly and do CRUD then, but it is other  story. For simplicity, in your case, child entity - Care - should only have FK setup of its parent CareCategory. So, just find category by its name, get its id, and set FK to a new Care object to be added. That's all, no need to extract the whole bunch of Cares via include like in your code - it's very inefficient.

Comment: Indeed, this could be a good way to improve the efficiency of this part of code. I do have a FK in the care table (I coded the one-to-many relationship as a fully defined relationship so there will be no issue to implement your little code improvement :))

Answer (score 0):

The issue with passing entities around in web applications is that when your controller passes an entity to serve as a model for the view, this goes to the view engine on the server to consume and build the HTML for the view, but what comes back to the controller when a form is posted or an AJAX call is made is *not* an entity. It is a block of data cast to look like an entity.

A better way to think of it is that your Add method accepts a view model called AddCareViewModel which contains all of the fields and FKs needed to create a new Care entity. Think about the process you would use in that case. You would want to validate that the required fields are present, and that the FKs (CareCategory etc.) are valid, then construct a Care entity with that data. Accepting an "entity" from the client side of the request is trusting the client browser to construct a valid entity without any way to validate it. Never trust anything from the client.

Personally I use the repository pattern to serve as a factory for entities, though this could also be a separate class. I use the Repository since it already has access to everything needed. Factory methods offer a standard way of composing a new entity and ensuring that all required data is provided:

```
var care = _careRepository.Create(addCareViewModel.CareCategoryId,
  /* all other required fields */);
care.OptionalField = addCareViewModel.OptionalField; // copy across optional data.
_context.SaveChanges(); // or ideally committed via a Unit of Work wrapper.
```

So for instance if a new Care requires a name, a category Id, and several other required fields, the Create method accepts those required fields and validates that they are provided. When it comes to FKs, the repository can load a reference to set the navigation property. (Also ensuring that a valid ID was given at the same time)

I don't recommend using a Generic Repository pattern with EF. (I.e. Repository()) Arguably the only reason to use a Repository pattern at all with EF would be to facilitate unit testing. Your code will be a lot simpler to understand/maintain, and almost certainly perform faster *without* a Repository. The DbContext already serves all of those needs and as a Unit of Work. When using a Repository to serve as a point of abstraction for enabling unit testing, instead of Generic, or per-entity repositories, I would suggest defining repositories like you would a Controller, with effectively a one-to-one responsibility.

If I have a CareController then I'd have a CareRepository that served all needs of the CareController. (Not just Care entities) The alternative is that the CareController would need several repository references, and each Repository would now potentially serve several controllers meaning it would have several reasons to change. Scoping a repository to serve the needs of a controller gives it only one reason to change. Sure, several repositories would potentially have methods to retrieve the same entity, but only one repository/controller should be typically responsible for creating/updating entities. (Plus repositories can always reference one another if you really want to see something as simple as Read methods implemented only once)

If using multiple repositories, the next thing to check is to ensure that the DbContext instance used is always scoped to the Web Request, and not something like Transient.

For instance if I have a CareRepository with a Create method that calls a CareCategoryRepository to get a CareCategory reference:

```
public Care Create(string name, int careCategoryId)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameOf(name));

    var care = new Care { Name = name };
    var careCategory = _careCategoryRepository.GetById(careCategoryId);
    care.CareCategory = careCategory;
    _context.Cares.Add(care);
}
```

We would want to ensure that the `DbContext` reference (_context) in all of our repositories, and our controller/UnitOfWork if the controller is going to signal the commit with `SaveChanges`, are pointing at the exact same single reference. This applies whether repositories call each other or a controller fetches data from multiple repositories.

Comment: I could do as you did in your second code snippet, it just changes the logic of "I want to add a Care to a category" into "I link an existing category to a Care". Plus that it would also solve my problem of having an entity for which changes aren't tracked. Also, reading your answer, there is also a part I may have misexplained, I do have a view model in my contrôler. That view model checks the valididy of the data first (layer API), then I call another class that maps the view model to the model (layer Application) from where I call thé repository to add ly entity (layer Infrastructure)

Comment: The relationship of something like a Care and CareCategory sounds like a many-to-one reference.  In the case of adding a new Child to a Parent where CareCategory is a parent of many Cares, then it would involve Creating the Care, loading the CareCategory eager loading it's Cares collection, and adding the new Care to the loaded CareCategory.Cares (instead of to the Care DbSet) before Saving.